# Mimimum time required for an NMOS transistor to operate as a switch?

Tags: switches, nmos, speed

How do I calculate the minimum time required for an NMOS transistor to work properly as a switch i.e. in the triode region?

When the time period is very narrow, the switch might not turn on and our desired operation might not work.

Is it possible to calculate via simulation or is it a technology-specified parameter?

Comment: negative_feedback are we done with this Q and A now? If so you should select an answer. If not then raise a comment for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is it possible to calculate via simulation or is it a
> technology-specified parameter?*

Read the appropriate data sheet for your MOSFET and there's a fair chance that rise/fall times will be specified and, the test circuit for measuring the rise/fall time will likely be shown.

You should also note that rise/fall times are heavily dependent on how you drive the gate. For instance, on many MOSFETs, to get the fastest times you need amps of current to charge/discharge the gate-source capacitance and, this requires specialist drivers. Hence, you could take a spice model and run it in a simulator but, if you don't model the driver circuit adequately you will likely get overly optimistic values for rise/fall times.

And of course, technology does play a role; technology choice does yield better performance in some areas compared to others and, significantly, the tech choice can affect your gate driver circuit so, be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

The series gate resistor (a.k.a. gate stopper resistor) sets a limit: The higher it is the slower the load current will rise (or the slower the on resistance will drop).

The reason behind this is that the MOSFET has a non-zero input capacitance which is shown as C<sub>iss</sub> in the datasheets. This capacitor gets charged and discharged through get stopper resistor so the resistor has a significant effect on switching times.

This may sound like the fastest switching will be achieved with zero gate stopper resistance. But zero gate stopper resistance brings another problems such as unwanted oscillations and loading the pre-driver section unnecessarily.